# How to run a Java EE project in Tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I have downloaded a jsp/servlet project and want to run it in Tomcat. I have deployed the project in

```
Tomcat-> webapp
```

Now on hitting the url in the browser i am getting a 404 error,please tell me what are the steps to run this project?/

Comment: show us what project you have donwloaded. there might be a problem with the project and/or your tomcat

Comment: Have you started the tomcat?! What is the URL you're hitting? Is the tomcat deployed on the 8080 port or any other port? Etc etc..

Comment: are you using any IDE ?? or manually doing it ??

Comment: You can run only WAR project on Tomcat because it not support many JEE feature. Use Tomcat as servlet container

Answer (score 3):

To deploy a web application in Tomcat without an IDE just copy the project into Tomcat's webapps folder. Then logon to Tomcat's main page with http:\localhost:8080 with a username and password. This is what you should do normally. Please elaborate on your issue.

Comment: this will just check if the tomcat is started , what else ??

Comment: if everything is alright with your project then tomcat directory will show all web projects whether it will work or not. 404 error is due to not redirecting to correct path http:\\localhost:8080\yourprojectname\index.jsp

Comment: thats what i have done.. i have simply copied the project into the webapps directory and tried to run using this url localhost:8005/projectname/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 404, it means your server is up and running, but your url is in correct. Please try the below url pattern :

If your war name is **HelloWorldJspExample**.war 
and jsp file name which you are trying to access is ***loginPage.jsp***

### then your url should be

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldJspExample/loginPage.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this question [execute-servlet-program](http://www.coderanch.com/t/361369/Servlets/java/execute-servlet-program)

Hope this will do.

Answer (score 0):

If You are copied a .war file into tomcat->webapps the please hit the

localhost:8080

if you see the home page of tamcat then goto manager and enter username and password and start your application.

if u cant see the tomcat home page please start the tomcat first goto tomcat->bin and click startup.bat file.

and for tomcat username and password please check the tomcat->conf->tomcat-users.xml file for username and password.

Comment: The tomcat is running fine and other applications deployed in this server are also running fine. However this particular application is getting 404 error.